# Powershell how to set advanced hard disk power settings

Tags: powershell

[image]

I found out with powershell command line how to change the basic power options.
Example:
         Set-PowerPlan -Plan Balanced

What I would also like to do is set the Hard disk to never turn off too with the High performance setting.  Is there a command line to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "powercfg"

```
& "powercfg" -x disk-timeout-ac 0
& "powercfg" -x disk-timeout-dc 0
```

For more info - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825694.aspx

Comment: I use this with psexec to remotely change these settings on clients :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the location:

```
C:\Windows\System32\powercfg.exe
```

Here are the commands to turn off a lot of unneeded power settings:

```
powercfg.exe -x -monitor-timeout-ac 0
powercfg.exe -x -monitor-timeout-dc 0
powercfg.exe -x -disk-timeout-ac 0
powercfg.exe -x -disk-timeout-dc 0
powercfg.exe -x -standby-timeout-ac 0
powercfg.exe -x -standby-timeout-dc 0
powercfg.exe -x -hibernate-timeout-ac 0
powercfg.exe -x -hibernate-timeout-dc 0
```

Thanks to kekimian I now have added a slew of commands that cover a range of power options for other users.  I know this will help someone as it has help me tremendously.